# Assign variable in pytorch

Tags: gpu, assign, pytorch

**I'd like to know if it is possble to the following code, but now using pytorch, where dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor. There's the code straight python (using numpy):** Basically I want to get the value of x that produces the min value of fitness.

```
import numpy as np
import random as rand
xmax, xmin       = 5, -5
pop              = 30
x                = (xmax-xmin)*rand.random(pop,1)
y                = x**2
[minz, indexmin] = np.amin(y), np.argmin(y)  
best             = x[indexmin]
```

**This is my attempt to do it:**

```
import torch
dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor 
def fit (x):
    return  x**2
def main():
    pop              = 30
    xmax, xmin       = 5, -5
    x                = (xmax-xmin)*torch.rand(pop, 1).type(dtype)+xmin
    y                = fit(x)
    [miny, indexmin] = torch.min(y,0)
    best             = x[indexmin] 
main()
```

The last part where I define the variable best as the value of x with index equal to indexmin it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here.

**The following messenge appears: RuntimeError:**

```
expecting vector of indices at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1501971235237/work/pytorch-0.1.12/torch/lib/THC/generic/THCTensorIndex.cu:405
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do as follows.

```
import torch
dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor 
def main():
    pop, xmax, xmin  = 30, 5, -5
    x                = (xmax-xmin)*torch.rand(pop, 1).type(dtype)+xmin
    y                = torch.pow(x, 2)
    [miny, indexmin] = y.min(0)
    best             = x.squeeze()[indexmin] # squeeze x to make it 1d

main()
```